# How do I import a library I find on Github into my existing project?

Tags: android, github

I would like to use the [SwipeListView](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview) as a View for a calendar app.

I'm trying to figure out how to put this onto my Activity.

I'm new to android and can't seem to figure out how to import the library into my current project in Eclipse so that I can use it.

What files do I need? Where do they go? They make it seem plug and play, but I can't seem to figure this one out.

Comment: what is your problem? in pulling ? or in using the library?

Comment: I download it as a zip file, unzip it, then in Eclipse I do File > Import, then I import the project from the unzipped folder.  This puts the entire project into my Workspace, however, the entire /src folder and all of its values have errors.

Comment: which errors are showing in problem tabs

Answer (score 0):

Please take time to read through development docs, most times questions like these get closed for 'lack of research'.

http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the first-floor, let me offer your the straight direction:

To add a reference to a library project, follow these steps:

Make sure that both the project library and the application project that depends on it are in your workspace. If one of the projects is missing, import it into your workspace.
In the Package Explorer, right-click the dependent project and select Properties.
In the Properties window, select the "Android" properties group at left and locate the Library properties at right.
Click Add to open the Project Selection dialog.
From the list of available library projects, select a project and click OK.
When the dialog closes, click Apply in the Properties window.
Click OK to close the Properties window.